# JMeter Command Line Output

Tags: command-line, jmeter

I'm running a JMeter test plan from command line and it's currently outputting something along the lines of:

```
Created the tree successfully using C:\*****\TestPlan.jmx
Starting the test @ Thu Oct 11 10:20:43 EDT 2012 (1349965243947)
Waiting for possible shutdown message on port 4445
Tidying up ...    @ Thu Oct 11 10:20:46 EDT 2012 (1349965246384)
... end of run
```

Is there any way to turn off this output and have the plan execute 'silently'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a way to do this, by following this article http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_redirection.php

and appending > NUL to the command

```
jmeter -n -t C:\***\TestPlan.jmx -Jhostname=%1 > NUL
```